# How to remove menus section from WordPress theme customizer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i tried to remove Menus from WordPress customizer see image
[image]

I tried the following code on functions.php file and every section was removed except Menus

```
  //Theme customizer

function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
   //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here

   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'title_tagline');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'colors');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'header_image');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'background_image');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'menus');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'custom_css');

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

I even tried

```
$wp_customize->remove_panel( 'menus');
```

but didn't worked i appriciate any help on this thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your theme have a `customizer.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
    function remove_customizer_settings( $wp_customize ){

    $wp_customize->remove_panel('nav_menus');
   }
   add_action( 'customize_register', 'remove_customizer_settings', 20 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above doesn't work for me but what did work is much more complicated. I found the answer at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228770/remove-nav-menus-from-customizer-using-a-theme but here it is again. Add the following to your theme's functions.php file.

```
add_action('customize_register', function ( $WP_Customize_Manager ){
    //check if WP_Customize_Nav_Menus object exist
    if (isset($WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus) && is_object($WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus)) {

        //Remove all the filters/actions resiterd in WP_Customize_Nav_Menus __construct
        remove_filter( 'customize_refresh_nonces', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'filter_nonces' ) );
        remove_action( 'wp_ajax_load-available-menu-items-customizer', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'ajax_load_available_items' ) );
        remove_action( 'wp_ajax_search-available-menu-items-customizer', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'ajax_search_available_items' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_register', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'customize_register' ), 11 );
        remove_filter( 'customize_dynamic_setting_args', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'filter_dynamic_setting_args' ), 10, 2 );
        remove_filter( 'customize_dynamic_setting_class', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'filter_dynamic_setting_class' ), 10, 3 );
        remove_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'print_templates' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'available_items_template' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_preview_init', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'customize_preview_init' ) );
        remove_filter( 'customize_dynamic_partial_args', array( $WP_Customize_Manager->nav_menus, 'customize_dynamic_partial_args' ), 10, 2 );

    }
}, -1); //Give it a lowest priority so we can remove it on right time
```